# same code in different actions of the controller in rails -- how to make DRY?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, dry

I have a controller with two different actions, but both need this same code, which is a little long, how can I allow them access to this same behavior but keep it DRY?

```
   @list = Contact.find :all,
      :select => "companies.name AS co_name, 
                  companies.id AS comp_id, 
                  COUNT(contact_emails.id) AS email_count, 
                  COUNT(contact_calls.id) AS call_count, 
                  COUNT(contact_letters.id) AS letter_count, 
                  COUNT(contact_postalcards.id) AS postalcard_count",

      :conditions => ['contact_emails.date_sent < ? and contact_emails.date_sent > ?', 
                      report_end_date, report_start_date],

      :joins => [
        "LEFT JOIN companies ON companies.id = contacts.company_id",
        "LEFT JOIN contact_emails ON contact_emails.contact_id = contacts.id",
        "LEFT JOIN contact_letters ON contact_letters.contact_id = contacts.id",
        "LEFT JOIN contact_postalcards ON contact_postalcards.contact_id = contacts.id",
        "LEFT JOIN contact_calls ON contact_calls.contact_id = contacts.id"
      ],
      #:group => "companies.id"
       :group => "companies.name"
    puts @list[0].attributes.inspect
```

Comment: This isn't answering your question, but I'm 90% sure all those "joins" could be replaced with "includes".  Something like this:  :include => [:companies, :contact_emails, :contact_letters, :contact_postalcards, :contact_calls].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should move this code to model:

```
# Contatct model

def self.get_list(report_start_date, report_end_date)
  self.find :all,
    :select => "companies.name AS co_name, 
              companies.id AS comp_id, 
              COUNT(contact_emails.id) AS email_count, 
              COUNT(contact_calls.id) AS call_count, 
              COUNT(contact_letters.id) AS letter_count, 
              COUNT(contact_postalcards.id) AS postalcard_count",

    :conditions => ['contact_emails.date_sent < ? and contact_emails.date_sent > ?', 
                  report_end_date, report_start_date],

    :joins => [
      "LEFT JOIN companies ON companies.id = contacts.company_id",
      "LEFT JOIN contact_emails ON contact_emails.contact_id = contacts.id",
      "LEFT JOIN contact_letters ON contact_letters.contact_id = contacts.id",
      "LEFT JOIN contact_postalcards ON contact_postalcards.contact_id = contacts.id",
      "LEFT JOIN contact_calls ON contact_calls.contact_id = contacts.id"
    ],
    #:group => "companies.id"
    :group => "companies.name"
end
```

Then you can use it in controllers:

```
@list = Contact.get_list(report_start_date, report_end_date)
```

Probably you can also split it to smaller parts and use scopes and defined associations instead of writing all of it on your own.

Comment: Most definitely. This code screams, "Get me out of the controller!" Pushing it to the model cleans up your code, and allows you to access the method from a rake task or more easily from the console if you wanted to pull up that list for a one-off report.

Comment: does this code look right, I'd love to clean it up, but I couldn't find a way....

Comment: Joins are usually ugly, the important things is that it is DRY: you only have to define it once in the model, but you can call it many times is various controllers, as klew pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a function for generating the count and join sql:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  def  self.get_list(report_start_date,    report_end_date)
    all(:select      => "companies.name AS co_name,
                        companies.id AS comp_id,
                        #{table_count_col(
                          :contact_emails, 
                          :contact_calls, 
                          :contact_letters, 
                          :contact_postalcards
                         )}",
        :conditions => ['contact_emails.date_sent < ?  AND
                         contact_emails.date_sent > ?',
                         report_end_date, report_start_date],
        :joins      => join_table(
                    :companies, 
                    :contact_emails, 
                    :contact_letters, 
                    :contact_postalcards, 
                    :contact_calls
                    ),
       )
  end
end
```

Where `table_count_col` and `table_join` are static methods inside `Contact` class:

```
  def self.table_count_col(*args)    
    args.collect do |table| 
      count_col = "#{table.to_s.gsub(/^contact_/,  '').singularize}_count"
      "COUNT(#{table}.id) AS #{count_col}"    
    end.join(",")
  end

  def self.table_join(*args)    
    args.collect do |table|
     "LEFT JOIN #{table} ON #{table}.id = contacts.company_id"
    end.join(",")
  end
```

Comment: table_count_col is a method on Contacts as is table_join?

Comment: Yes, they are static methods on Contact class.

Comment: I like it +1 for helping simplify -- may need to implement in phases